# Cannot install Sed in tools directory, Permission Denied

Tags: linux, sed, lfs

I am building Linux From Scratch.
Here's the error I faced during installation of sed.

```
/tools/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/tools/bin/sed': Permission denied
```

Because of this I cannot compile Linux Header Files

```
/bin/sh: sed: command not found
Makefile:629: arch//Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'arch//Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Did you run `make install` as root?

Comment: we need more information - lfs version? which chapter? are you doing everything by the book, or did you change something?

Comment: LFS ver 8.2 and No I didn't change anything. I'm doing everything as elaborated in the book.